# How can I create a new instance of DateTime in specific time zone?

Tags: c#, datetime

Given a specific TimeZoneInfo instance how can I create a new DateTime instance in the specified time zone? For example if I have:

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time");
var date = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, tz));
```

I am always getting 12/31/2016 7:00:00 PM regardless of what DateTimeKind I define (Utc, Local or Unspecified).

How can I declare a new DateTime that will be January 1st of 2017 at 0:00:00 in US Eastern Standard Time?

Comment: There are many ways, one of which utilizes [`TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset(v=vs.110).aspx), there's also [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(DateTime)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396378(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(DateTimeOffset)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb459779(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can you please explain what is your expected output? Do you want to convert a `DateTime` *from* a specific time zone to local time?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma No I want to define a new specific DateTime for a specific time zone. For example I want a DateTime instance for January 1st, 2017 EST - US Eastern Standard Time. I don't want to rely on Local server time because server might not be where my client is. So I have TimeZoneInfo saved for each client and I want to instantiate time based on that.

Comment: `DateTime` does only differentiates between local and UTC time, there is no Time Zone specific information in it. You either have to convert from your time-zone to UTC (and then to local time if you want) or use `DateTimeOffset`, which, even if it has not Time Zone information, it at least has built-in offset from UTC stored. Also note that storing timestamps using client time zone is almost always a bad idea, is better to store UTC date/time and then do the time-zone conversion inside the client when visualizing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You  can use TimeZoneInfo to retrieve your zone

You can find [timezones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx) here

```
var zn = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
```

to express that you are using a local eastern standard time use `DateTimeOffset` struct instead of DateTime

```
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), zn.BaseUtcOffset);
```

Why `DateTimeOffset`

*`DateTimeOffset is a representation of instantaneous time (also known as absolute time).`*

Comment: I need to use the TimeZoneInfo instance since that is available to me, can you tell me how TimeSpan maps to TimeZoneInfo? You are just hand coding the -5 time difference.

Comment: @Marko what you mean since that is available  to me did you mean to retrieve the zone dynamically

Comment: This is the correct answer for me as it gives me DateTime instance via dateTimeOffset.DateTime and it also gives me an offset of -5 via dateTimeOffset .Offset.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the timezoneID as you are using it to specify what timezone you want to create your datetime object.

```
TimeZoneInfo tzone= TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard 
Time");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

later you just convert the datetime to your required timezone.

```
var datetime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt , tzone);
```

this is the link where you can find all timezones ID. [TimeZoneIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx)

Thank you, hope this can help you.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` will provide the time using the systems current timezone setting. I think you meant `DateTime.UtcNow`?